# Changing the Attribute table view in QGIS 3

Tags: attribute-table, qgis-3

How does one change the Attribute table view on QGIS 3?

An initial answer says to use the <kbd>Switch to Table view</kbd> button but I can't seem to find this button.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

The Attribute Table view can be changed with two lower right buttons ('Switch to form view' and 'Switch to table view'), see image below.

[image: AT_view]

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Docs | Table view vs Form view](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#table-view-vs-form-view)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seen the Table View and Form view options now.

Comment: [@Brian Muraba](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/130230/brian-muraba), if my answer fulfils your request, please accept it as an answer. Thanks